# Using Script Task How to Read only half of a text in one line from a file

Tags: c#, ssis

There is a code that generates a log file which has info on it based on what happens after after package execution.

In that log file if a piece of the code fails that log file one of the lines will state

```
< 2023-08-31 13:02:39.749 No such file or directory.
```

In the script task which is using c# I have the following code

```
string log = Dts.Variables["LogFile"].Value.ToString();
        string searchTarget = "No such file or directory.";
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(log))
        {
            if(line.Contains(searchTarget))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("file doesn't exist");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("file does exist");
                break;
            }
        }
```

I wanted it to be like if you see the phrase "No such file or directory" in the log file then give the message that file doesn't exist.

However its giving me the message "file does exist"

I believe its because its looking for that entire phrase as its own line which doesn't exist since the timestamp in connected to it.

Is there a way where it can only read that phrase despite it being next to a timestamp?

Comment: You are looking through every line in the file, you dont need to do that.  The break;  may be breaking out of the if/else statement not the for loop.  Just read the first line in the file if that is where it is.